# Jenkins within the docker is failing to pull the image

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy

I have installed oracle virtual box and docker toolbox on my windows laptop. 
I have created the Jenkins container inside docker. 
Jenkins is working well. 
But when I created the sample pipeline it fails.

Following is the docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.3
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.12
 Git commit:        774a1f4eee
 Built:             Mon Mar  4 10:36:44 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.1
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.5
  Git commit:       74b1e89e8a
  Built:            Thu Jul 25 21:27:55 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Following is the pipeline:

```
pipeline {

   agent {
        docker { image 'hello-world'  }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the error :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'hello-world'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"cat\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(Docker.groovy:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:114)
    at
```

Comment: "exec: \"cat\":? seems like you are modified the Dockerfile or pipline seems incomplete

Comment: I have given the pipeline in the query. There is no dockerfile. Right now I am writing down the commands in the pipeline itself.

Comment: are you able to run the docker image by itself locally? I would start there

Comment: Yes locally it works fine.

Comment: OK then how did you create the image? Does that have a Dockerfile?

Comment: I created using 'docker run' command.

Comment: Please add those steps in the details.

Comment: what do you mean ...… which steps ? 
I have already added what I have done in the query itself.

Comment: the full command you used to create the image, your docker version, your OS version, and your jenkins version

Comment: 'docker run hello-world' is used directly in docker it worked well. 
Jenkins version 2.190.1
For docker version and OS version see the updated query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'hello-world'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"cat\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

You do not have **docker** in your image that is hello-world, and `docker version` will suppose to run inside container.

Second thing

```
steps {
                sh 'echo hello form container'
      }
```

Running bash or sh will not working **hello-word** container, as this container is based from scratch and there is not bash or sh. it just container execute hello file.

[Dockerfile-helloworld](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/b715c35271f1d18832480bde75fe17b93db26414/amd64/hello-world/Dockerfile)

Change pipeline and also base image if you just want to say hello to docker.

```
pipeline {

   agent {
        docker { image 'alpine'  }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo hello form container'
            }
        }
    }
}
```